# Is there a way to generate a SQL script for deploying to Azure SQL database from a SQL Project using Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: sql-server, azure, deployment, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I am trying to make changes to the existing Azure SQL Database. I have a sql project created using Visual Studio, and trying to make changes to the Azure SQL Database using Azure CLI.

I am stuck at the step where the sql script is generated, after generating the sql script I will be deploying it in the database:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
>   "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Projects\Test\Test_DB\Test_DB.sqlproj" 
>   /t:Build;Publish  /p:DeployOnBuild=false /p:Configuration=Install
>   /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Projects\Test\Test_DB\Test_DB.publish.xml" /p:UpdateDatabase=false

Error I got:

> error MSB4018: The "SqlPublishTask" task failed unexpectedly. error
>   MSB4018: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   AdalException: No mapping between account names and security IDs was
>   done.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Looks similar to [this one](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889505-no-mapping-between-account-names-and-security-ids). Something wrong with your AAD it seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that there is no mapping between account names and security IDs. This means there is a GPO setting which is used for domain computer controllers with orphaned account details. Those accounts couldn’t resolved to correct SID.

Most likely the account used in the GPO was removed from the directory, or the GPO account name is typed incorrectly or wrong somehow.

Or, as mentioned in the link posted by NiceWork, somewhere in one of your security roles you have a member that is no longer part of the domain, or a username that for some reason cannot be resolved.